# get string from text field that contains a certain string

Tags: java

I am reading text from a external .txt file to a text area on a jframe. 
In the text file I have "Name: Andrew".

When the .txt text file is read into the textArea in a jframe, I want to get "Andrew" in the text area and then using the file writer i want to create a new .txt text with the name I got from the text area "Andrew" as the name of the new .txt file.

I have tried using

```
If (JTextField1.getText.contains("Name")){
...
}
```

but that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (JTextField1.getText().contains("Name")) {
    string name = JTextField1.getText().split(": ")[1];
}
```